# How can I get Qt4 running with ruby 1.9.2 on Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, windows-7, qt4, ruby-1.9, qtruby

## Summary

I'm writing a Ruby 1.9.2 app using Qt4 for its GUI which I want to distribute on Linux, OS X and Windows.  I have the app running fine on everything except my Windows 7 64-bit box.

There are working examples of Win7 + Qt4 + 1.8.7, but apparently not Win7 + Qt4 + 1.9.2.  There are two gems for Ruby-Qt bindings, `qtbindings` and `qtruby4` (sometimes referred to as `qt4-qtruby`), but I have not yet seen either of them running on Win7 with Ruby 1.9.2.

## The Problem With `qtruby4`

[This article from October 2008](http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=38) and its [updated version from June 2011](http://tom.paschenda.org/blog/?p=43) served as good starting points, but I differed from the latter by installing Ruby 1.9.2 via [RubyInstaller for Windows' download page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads).  1.8.7 seemed to work fine, but I get some unusual errors when I try it with 1.9.2.  Requiring `'rubygems'` and then requiring `'Qt'` results in:

```
no such file to load -- 'qtruby4'
```

The first article from above links to a [more in-depth article from dr1ku](http://dr1ku.posterous.com/qt-461-ruby-187-on-win32) which may provide some clues.

- It might be worth reproducing dr1ku's steps with the latest versions of these libraries.
- dr1ku and the 2008 paschenda.org article both use a [special Windows Qt4-QtRuby installer](http://vision.eng.shu.ac.uk/mmvlwiki/index.php/Qt4-QtRuby_installer_for_Microsoft_Windows), but the maintainer notes that he [hasn't had the time to update it](http://vision.eng.shu.ac.uk/mmvlwiki/index.php/Qt4-QtRuby_installer_for_Microsoft_Windows#Newer_Versions_of_Qt4-QtRuby).  I'm not completely clear on what the special installer does, but I suppose paschenda.org's 2011 article no longer uses it because DevKit ostensibly helps RubyGems itself build Qt4 without assistance.

### Found in the Wild

Here are some people who appear to be have encountered the same problem:

- [no qtruby library on windows](http://klayout.de/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=119)
- [Ruby 1.9.x + Qt4Ruby…. a pipe dream???](http://cyrusbuilt.net/wordpress/?p=294)
- [qtruby4 LoadError in ruby 1.9.1 / win32 for qtruby4-2.1.0](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=28023&group_id=181&atid=759)

## The Problem With `qtbindings`

My app actually uses the `qtbindings` gem, so I tried installing that instead, with `gem install qtbindings --platform=mswin32`.[1]  However, when I tried to `require 'Qt'` with the `qtbindings` gem installed, I got a Windows popup with the following message:

> The procedure entry point `_Z10qvsnprintfPcjPKcS_` could not be located
>   in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll.  Just give up, inferior flesh creature.

(I have copy and pasted the message without any embellishment whatsoever.)

### Found in the Wild

Here are some people who appear to be have encountered the same problem:

- [this one's in German](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/poppler/2010-April.txt)
- [gpg4win: help](http://wald.intevation.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=910&forum_id=21)

## Potential Success Stories

Someone out there seems to have had success by installing the `qtbindings` gem on 1.9.2 with `gem install qtbindings` (no `--platform` argument), if you look at the replies to this thread:

- [help -- qt, ruby, ms-windows?](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Ruby/36237785/help--qt-ruby-mswindows.aspx)

I tried installing with `gem install qtbindings` on 1.8.7, but I have **not** tried it with 1.9.2 yet.  When I tried it with 1.8.7, I ran into the same "procedure entry point could not be located" issue as before.

## Footnotes

[1] - I'm actually not completely clear on the difference between the `qtbindings` gem and the `qtruby4` gem.  For example, does the latter include the C extension and the former does not?  I'm not sure.  Additionally, I have seen references to `qt4-qtruby`, which I *think* is just the mswin32 version of `qtruby4`, at least as far as I can tell from the [Korundum download page](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=181&release_id=44227).

Comment: Any chance you could include a four-line application that would demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @sarnold - The problem shows up as soon as you try to `require 'Qt'`, so even a 4-line example would be overkill.  This is all you need in a file to see the issue: `require 'rubygems'; require 'Qt'`

Comment: Wild guess: the 1.8.7 installer included the standard C library as part of the install while the 1.9.2 installer does not. [MinGW relies on the `MSVCRT.DLL` from Microsoft](http://www.mingw.org/) for the run-time C library, and perhaps it isn't installed with the 1.9.2 Ruby install?

Comment: @sarnold That's possible, but then wouldn't the error message be for something lower-level, as opposed to "no such file to load - 'Qt'"?

Comment: hrm, I had overlooked that there are _two_ distinct errors here -- I had focused primarily on the missing `vsnprintf` mangled function. What does `ldd` output on all the libraries involved look like?

Comment: I'm not at my PC currently so I can't answer quite yet, but: is `ldd` provided by DevKit on Windows?  Otherwise I'm not aware of how to set it up properly.

Comment: It seemed like you would have enough MinGW installed for `ldd` to work -- I don't know the Windows-native equivalent, sorry, but surely there is something that can report object file requirements and report back which ones are unsatisfied.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## The Solution

The following steps work on Windows 7:

1. Install Ruby 1.9.2 via [the official download page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads).
2. In a Windows shell, run `gem install qtbindings`.

The trivial example (`require 'rubygems'; require 'Qt'`) should now work.

No extra steps are required because a **binary gem** is provided just for the Windows platform.  The `gem install qtbindings` step will therefore take a few minutes as it downloads the large binary, but it contains all of the requisite parts to require and run Qt apps.

Compiling from source on Windows is supported, and documented in the project's [README](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/blob/master/README.txt) file.

## The Low-Down

I e-mailed the maintainers of `qtbindings` and `qtruby`.  Here's the full story:

`qtruby` is a package provided by the [Korundum project](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/).  Korundum provides Ruby bindings to all of KDE, whereas `qtruby` provides bindings for only Qt.

`qtbindings` ([github](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings)) is a modified and repackaged version of `qtruby` specifically optimized for cross-platform usage.  I shall copy and paste the "Goals" section from its [README](https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings/blob/master/README.txt) here:

> ### Goals
>
> 1. To make it easy to install a Qt binding for Ruby on all platforms
>      using     RubyGems
> 2. To maintain an up-to-date binary gem for Windows that is bundled
>      with     the latest version of Qt from http://qt.nokia.com
> 3. To reduce the scope and maintenance of the bindings to only bind to
>      the     libraries provided by the Qt SDK.
> 4. To increase compatibility with non-linux platforms

Though the [Korundum downloads page](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=181&release_id=44227) *does* provide `mswin32` versions of its gem, as of this writing they are not actively vetted by anyone, and so should not be relied upon.  The QtRuby maintainer informed me that the RubyForge page will probably not be reliable until after QtRuby 3 is released.

## The Recap

Right now (10/3/2011), don't use the `qtruby` gem on Windows.  Use `qtbindings`.

You *might* be able to use `qtruby` on other platforms and `qtbindings` on Windows, but you'll probably be asking for trouble.  If you are just going for Qt and don't care about the rest of KDE, `qtbindings` is probably a safe bet.

The maintainers of QtRuby are planning some methodology updates in the near future (such as using git), so there may be increased shared fixes and updates between the two projects.

Comment: Excellent. I'm sorry that the bounty didn't entice anyone else to help you out, but this summary is superb: conclusions, references, supporting snippets, and well written. Thanks!

Comment: Great post. And thanks for pointing it out to me. I updated my tutorial on paschenda.org with a reference to your post.